# Master-Detail: how to add a command instead of a detail page

Tags: xamarin.forms, master-detail, freshmvvm

I have a Xamarin.Forms app with FreshMvvm. I am trying to use Master-Detail architecture, like this:

```
        var masterDetailNav = new FreshMasterDetailNavigationContainer();
        masterDetailNav.Init("Menu");
        masterDetailNav.AddPage<AboutPageModel>("About", null);
        masterDetailNav.AddPage<PageModels.CoverageCalculator.CoverageCalculatorPageModel>("Coverage Calculator", null);
        MainPage = masterDetailNav;
```

This is good, but I need to add navigation elements that would do something OTHER than opening detail pages. E.g. I may need to open some website in the browser or make a call etc. Is it doable, and if so, how?

Comment: Any idea anybody?